How to manually call the onClusterItemClick() method from a ClusterItem object in Kotlin Jetpack Compose?
I am using clustering to show hundreds of markers on a google map, and I have implement some logic to show when a ClusterItem is clicked. I also have some search functionality, allowing users to find a specific ClusterItem by a string and taking the user to the marker location.
However, I am unable replicate all the same behaviour between a user clicking on a ClusterItem on the map and when a ClusterItem is selected through my search bar.
The main differences are that when a ClusterItem is clicked, the ClusterItem Snippet and Tittle appear, as well as links to directions to google maps. These seem to be built into the ClusterItem.OnClick() method, and I don't know how to access that method in Jetpack Compose.
I know that in a View framework, I could call something like theSearchedClusterItem.onClusterItemClick() or theSearchedClusterItem.showInfoWindow(). Is there something similar that I could do in Jetpack Compose?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
